# Can Dynamic Feature 'playmonkeys' play audio to both channels?

Tags: asterisk, dynamic-feature

How can I get the audio from the DYNAMIC_FEATURES "playmonkeys" to play on both channels at the same time? Not just the opposite channel.

```
playmonkeys => #9,peer,Playback,tt-monkeys  ;Allow both the caller and callee to play tt-monkeys to the opposite channel
```

Thanks for any ideas.

-Iggy

Answer (score 0):

Features.conf **application** can play caller,calle or both.

For more info see http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/AdditionalConfig_id256654.html

"playmonkeys" is not a feature, it is just a sample.

Comment: From the link you provided `<FeatureName> => <DTMF_sequence>,<ActivateOn>[/<ActivatedBy>]
,<Application>([<AppArguments>])[,MOH_Class]`

Comment: I thought the "playmonkeys" was a sample "applicationmap." Doesn't seem "peer" or "self" doesn't play audio for both caller and callee but just either one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ActivateOn =Both. On the same link